# How to test Nestjs interceptor?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, interceptor, nestjs

I can't find any explanation on how to test interceptors in NestJS

This simple example intercepts a POST query to add an attribute to an Example Model provided in the body.

```js
@Injectable()
export class SubscriberInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  async intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler,
  ): Promise<Observable<ExampleModel>> {
    let body: ExampleModel = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body;
    body = {
      ...body,
      addedAttribute: 'example',
    };
    context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body = body;
    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

I would like to test what's happening in the intercept function.

So far:

```js
const interceptor = new SubscriberInterceptor();

describe('SubscriberInterceptor', () => {
  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(interceptor).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('#intercept', () => {
    it('should add the addedAttribute to the body', async () => {
      expect(await interceptor.intercept(arg1, arg2)).toBe({ ...bodyMock, addedAttribute: 'example' });
    });
  });
});
```

My question: Should I mock only `arg1: ExecutionContext` and `arg2: CallHandler`? If so, how to mock `arg1` and `arg2`? Else How should I proceed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right, you should mock the `arg1` and `arg2`,then pass them to `intercept` method, here is the solution:

`SubscriberInterceptor.ts`:

```
interface ExecutionContext {
  switchToHttp(): any;
}
interface CallHandler {
  handle(): any;
}
interface Observable<T> {}
interface ExampleModel {}

interface NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<ExampleModel>>;
}

export class SubscriberInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  public async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<ExampleModel>> {
    let body: ExampleModel = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body;
    body = {
      ...body,
      addedAttribute: 'example'
    };
    context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body = body;
    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

Unit test, mock chained method of `executionContext`

```
import { SubscriberInterceptor } from './';

const interceptor = new SubscriberInterceptor();

const executionContext = {
  switchToHttp: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  getRequest: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
};

const callHandler = {
  handle: jest.fn()
};

describe('SubscriberInterceptor', () => {
  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(interceptor).toBeDefined();
  });
  describe('#intercept', () => {
    it('t1', async () => {
      (executionContext.switchToHttp().getRequest as jest.Mock<any, any>).mockReturnValueOnce({
        body: { data: 'mocked data' }
      });
      callHandler.handle.mockResolvedValueOnce('next handle');
      const actualValue = await interceptor.intercept(executionContext, callHandler);
      expect(actualValue).toBe('next handle');
      expect(executionContext.switchToHttp().getRequest().body).toEqual({
        data: 'mocked data',
        addedAttribute: 'example'
      });
      expect(callHandler.handle).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/mock-function/57730120/index.spec.ts
  SubscriberInterceptor
    ✓ should be defined (10ms)
    #intercept
      ✓ t1 (11ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.235s, estimated 3s
```

Comment: How does this work when getRequest is not a method of ExecutionContext? It is a method of the object returned from switchtoHttp().

Comment: This works because using `.mockReturnThis()` as the return value for all the mocks will return executionContext in all cases.