# How to create mockObject in Jest test framework without worrying about object's properties

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I am using `NestJS` with `Jest` framework to test `NestJS Interceptor`. I wanted to write a unit test for `interceptors`. Interceptor function asks for two parameters.  I already created a mock object of `CallHandler` because It requires minimal one mandatory parameter. However, I want to create a spy/mock object of `ExecutionContext` which asks for many parameters.  How to achieve that?

Interceptor looks like:

```js
@Injectable()
export class GetFlowDefinitionInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  public intercept(_context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<FlowUI> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      map(flow => {
        flow.name = 'new name'
        return flow;
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Tests look like

```js
 it('interceptor test', () => {
    let _context: ExecutionContext = {}; <- that i want to mock, error below
    let next: CallHandler = {
      handle: function () {
        return of({});
      }
    }
    let result = new GetFlowDefinitionInterceptor().intercept(_context, next);
    expect(result.name).toEqual('new name');
  });
```

Error

```js
let _context: ExecutionContext

Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ExecutionContext': getClass, getHandler, getArgs, getArgByIndex, and 3 more.ts(2740)
```

Comment: take a look at this question that could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730120/how-to-test-nestjs-interceptor

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the best option, but you could write `let result = new GetFlowDefinitionInterceptor().intercept(_context as any, next);` to ignore the compilation issue. (the `as any` is very important)

Answer (score 0):

You could test your logic without testing an interceptor.

**1)** Separate and test the logic:

```js
export class FlowDefinitionMap {
  map(flow: FlowDefinition) {
    return {...flow, name: 'new name'};
  }
}

it('it should replace name', () => {
  const result = new FlowDefinitionMap().map({name: 'old name'});
  expect(result.name).toEqual('new name');
});
```

**2)** Use the new `FlowDefinitionMap` in the interceptor:

```js
@Injectable()
export class GetFlowDefinitionInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  public intercept(_context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<FlowUI> {
    const flowDefinitionMap = new FlowDefinitionMap();

    return next.handle().pipe(
      map(flow => {
        return flowDefinitionMap.map(flow);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this option, however, I do not cover the lines of interceptors in Jest Code Coverage. I need to test callHandler returned value.